# How do I resize sap.m.TextArea manually in sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am implementing sap.m.TextArea. I want a feature similar to [resizable sap.ui.common.TextArea](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/27/text-area-resize-handler-thingy/). I want to expand the sap.m.textArea manually using mouse. How can I achieve that?

Thanks,

Teja.

Comment: Why would you want to expand the TextArea manually? have you looked at the property `growing`? If you set that to true, the TextArea grows/shrinks based on the content.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Though SAP doesn't recommend customizing standard CSS, I created one css class 'textarea' and written below line of code:

```
   .textarea.sapMTextArea .sapMInputBaseContentWrapper 
{
    resize: vertical;
}
```